# Android: Obtaining the dimension of the button

Tags: android, button, dimension

I am having a dynamic layout where there is a imagebutton named ButtonQ.
I would like to set the dimension of the ButtonQ and then to see if it is correct, I have added a toast.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();
    measure_dimension();
}


    private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) 
    {
        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        return point;
    }

    public void measure_dimension() 
    { 
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = getDisplaySize(display); 
        int screen_width = size.x;
        int screen_height = size.y;

        int target_height = Math.min(screen_height, 600);
        int target_width = Math.min(screen_width, 600);
        int target_dimension = Math.min(target_height, target_width);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(target_dimension, target_dimension);  // width, height
        buttonQ.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
        image_height = target_height;
        image_width = target_width;

        Toast.makeText(Game_middle.this, "buttonQ height:"+ buttonQ.getHeight() +"\nbuttonQ width=" + buttonQ.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

### Question:

The toast reports the height and the width of ButtonQ are both 0.
Why?

Comment: Why don't you check the values the same way you set them: by getLayoutParams()? It's just a supposition, but might it be that it's returning 0 because getHeight()/Width() both return the layout size, and you're not showing buttonQ yet?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I can get the dimension with values now. But actually what are the differences?

Comment: I've updated my previous comment, check if it fits your scenario.

Comment: thanks for your advice! The buttonQ is a imageView located at center of a linearlayout, subject to the size of different device and my images are not high definition enough, I am trying to set the dimension of buttonQ to cap at 600 (what unit is that 600 referring actually?). And then I use a Handler to delay the setImage to the ButtonQ by 300ms in order the above to be completed... sounds the procedures are a little bit clumpsy?

Comment: The size you're passing is in pixels. You might want to use TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP to specify the size in dp unit - instead of using time delays, I'd use an asynchronous mechanism such as CountDownLatch to achieve it, it's quite more secure than using timers. It might also be that the 0's you're getting from the getHeight()/Width() methods have something to do with that.

Comment: If then I am trying to get pixels and in that case i just let it be...Let me learn about CountDownLatch now..thanks a lot! it would be great if u can make the above as ans =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the analogue way you're setting your height and width: via `getLayoutParams()`. If you want to set the params dynamically, I wouldn't use pixels directly but the `dp` unit, using `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`.

Regarding to synchronization, in that example I'd definitely use asynchronous mechanisms, such as `CountDownLatch` or `Semaphore` mechanisms. It's quite more secure this way than using temporary timers. You may want to check the `CountDownLatch(1)` example in the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the button dimensions where popLayout is the button name in your case

```
popupLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
width = popupLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
height = popupLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
```